# Can I build anything on an Oasis in Civilization 5?

Tags: civilization-5

Can I build anything on an Oasis or do anything with it in Civilization 5?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot build any improvements other than roads and railroads on an **oasis** tile.

Comment: How do I get their resources then, build something next to it?

Comment: You should be able to use their resources by assigning workers to them in the city, if the tile is within the bounds of the city of course. That's different from building improvements.

Comment: Oh really, ill have to try that...

Comment: It's possible to build a city on an oasis, but it is destroyed in the process.